# Relative error when exact quantity is $e^{-200}$ and significant digits; what's going on?

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation, rounding-error, significant-figures

Caveat: I've already searched for this topic here in MSE but also on other sites, but I have not still found anything that can answer my doubt.

---

I'm checking my own implementation of a code. The context is not important. The correct value is $x=e^{-200}$, and I computed $\hat{x}$ with my routine.

- I computed the *absolute error* $|x- \hat{x}|=1.2\cdot10^{-14}$. This means that in $\hat{x}$ I have **14 correct digits** of $x$.
- If I compute now the *relative error* I have $\frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|x|} = 8.67 \cdot 10^{72} $. I know it is related to the number of significant digits, and in this case the denominator $x=e^{-200}$ is **not** zero (even in is really small).

I'm really puzzled because I can't understand what is going on: I mean, the result of the relative error is saying me that the approximation is poor? But the first $14$ digits are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $x$ has 86 zeros after the decimal period. So having determimed the first 14 zeros you are still 72 zeros away from the real thing.

More technically, your error is $10^{72}$ bigger than the actual $x$, which is what your quotient is showing.

Comment: Okay, so the relative error takes into account **ALL** the significant digits of the number. Right? 
Since $e^{-200}$ has 87 zeros before the beginning of the significant digits, and my $\hat{x}$ is exact only on the first $14$ (which are all zeros), the relative error of $10^72$ is saying me the information about what you call the "real thing".

Comment: Yes. For instance $10^{-15}$ is within your tolerance, and it is $10^{72}$ times bigger than $x$.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "within your tolerance"? @MartinArgerami

Comment: Do you mean that even if $\hat{x}$ is accurate up to $15$ digits, it is $10^{72}$ times bigger? @MartinArgerami

Comment: Yes. Like I said, $10^{-15}$ is accurate up to 14 digits, and $10^{72}$, times bigger than $x$.

Comment: Clear, thanks. Do you have some reference for those type of problems related to numerics? Is Higham's book "accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms" one of the best choices?

Comment: I cannot comment, sorry. My knowledge of numerical analysis is very very basic.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway for the answer and the comments :-)